# What is this small grass plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, watering

Got it as a gift, and was told to water it every two days. Seems a little frequent to me, what plant is this?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's an [Asparagus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagus) - [*Asparagus densiflorus* 'sprengeri'](http://davesgarden.com/guides/pf/go/1850/#b) is what it most resembles, but this plant usually becomes mound like, with the 'fronds' drooping over - this may happen as time goes by I guess. It's commonly known as the sprengerii fern - it's not actually a fern, but, although it doesn't like sitting in water, it doesn't like to dry out, which is why you've been advised to water it frequently. Watering should be reduced a bit in winter though.

Comment: thanks so much Bamboo! I think you're right! Now that I know what it is, it's much easier to care for.